# How to sort an array only by using argmin()

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

How can I sort an array in an ascending order only by using `argmin()`?

For example, if I define `sort_function(x)` which returns the ascending order of `x` only by using `argmin()` and do:

```
print(sort_function(np.array([1,6,3,7]))
```

the result should be `[1 3 6 7]`.

Comment: Is your question *"how do I define this `sort_function`?"* ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this with `argmin` and not `argsort`?

Comment: What do you mean by _only using_? You could take more or less any sort algo and replace `x > y` with `np.argmin((x, y))`. I take it that wouldn't count?

Answer (score 5):

Here it is, in blazing fast `O(N ** 2)` -

1. Call `np.argmin` on the list
2. Pop the element at that index
3. Repeat until list is empty

```
def sort_function(x):
    y = list(x)
    while y:
        yield y.pop(np.argmin(y))

list(sort_function(np.array([1, 6, 3, 7])))
[1, 3, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Ah! that was fast

Comment: or just `return [y.pop(np.argmin(y)) for _ in x]`

Comment: @Dark Please note that cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ is being sarcastic when he says "blazing fast". This is a really dumb way to do sorting.

Comment: Haha @PM2Ring I mean about posting the solution ; ).

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Mhm actually it doesn't work because `pop` induces side effects during iteration :(

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ On 3.6.1 it [seems to be working fine](https://repl.it/repls/DisguisedWhoppingUlyssesbutterfly). I was also thinking whether the `y` reference gets updated inside the comprehension but it seems to be..

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Okay, that might be why. This was tested on python3.4 (Ipython5). I wonder what changed for this to work in 3.6

Comment: This solution uses `pop`, `list`, `yield`, `while`, and even `def` but the OP asked for `argmin` only :(